# How to achieve 100% cpu usage on windows server 2008

Tags: multithreading, f#, parallel-processing, cpu-usage

I need to run a very time cost program. This program is made by multi-threads. But when I run it on my sever (windows server 2008 , cpu-E5 2680), it had a same performance with my PC, only with little speed improvement.

So I made a Fib function for testing and I want use all the cores to run this Fib function at the same time with close to 100% CPU usage.

```
let rec fib n =
    if n> 450 then 10
    else fib (n+1) + fib (n+2)

let intial (x:BackgroundWorker) =
    x.DoWork.Add(fun e ->
    ignore(fib 1)
    )

    x.RunWorkerCompleted.Add(fun e ->())
    x
let arr = [|for i = 0 to 7 do yield new BackgroundWorker()|]  
let _ = arr |> Array.map intial
while true do
    let res =arr |> Array.map (fun e ->
                if e.IsBusy then
                    ()
                else
                    e.RunWorkerAsync())
    ()
```

When I set only one thread , one core will reach to 100% usage.This does make sense.But when try to increase the number of thread. It show that the CPU usage decrease when the number of thread increase. For example , when I use 8 thread, there will be 8 CPU working with a about 50% usage, and also another one seems to be the thread of the 'While' part. Others seems to be not on working.

So what's wrong here? I really need a demo which can do some parallel computing with a high level CPU usage.

Comment: Possibly an overhead issue with frequently calling `IsBusy` from the main thread - try inserting a call to `Thread.Sleep` in the while loop

Comment: If all you want to do is chew up CPU time, make a worker thread that counts to 2^64-1 and launch as many instances of these as you have cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your program is limited by the cost of switching threads - it is doing too little useful work.  A call to just start job on a thread is 10's of thousands of cycles best case.  Calculating the fibonacci of 20 is trivial by comparison.

Remember the fibonacci sequence gets very large, very quickly.  You will exceed integer, float and double by the time you reach 450.  (I believe the number is about 4.9E93.  64 bit integers run out around 2E19, and doubles loose integer resolution well before that.

Comment: Note - this doesn't actually calculate fibonacci and the function takes a significant amount of time to complete.

Comment: Similar, to John's comment above, can you change your function around so that you give each thread 1/8th of the work and then call RunWorkerAsync() once and then wait for them all to complete.  Additionally, is there a cross thread dependency?  Are you expecting one thread to compute an earlier result to use in the other thread?  That overhead would be likely cause your algorithm to scale much worse than O(n processors).

Comment: I think the idea is that the function is a joke, but that if you had a real task it is easy to achieve 100% CPU usage.  Also, the OP won't see your comment here - you need to comment on the question for the OP to be notified.

Comment: Thanks you all guys！！！ sincerely! You know my English is not very good. I don't think the fib matters a lot ,even though it has a problem of out bound. Finally i decide to use Array.Parallel.... it can do what i want automatically and succefully all the cpu is running with more than 90% usage. Thanks Harvey, I am sure your suggestion will work. But i still wonder why 'BackgroundWorker' I wrote failed but the 'Array.Parallel' succeed.